# Encryption feature of ICS not working on emulator

Tags: android, encryption, android-source

I'm trying to test Encryption feature of ICS on emulator.

To enable "Encrypt Phone", we ran "telnet localhost 5554" and then "power capacity 100".

After this when I click on "Encrypt Phone: button of final confirmation I get a screen having "Android" icon on it but nothing happens.
I checked logcat it gives following error.
06-05 18:08:49.760: E/Cryptfs(31): Cannot get size of block device

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sushil

Comment: I would guess that it doesn't work on the emulator, have you tried on a device?

Comment: Tim, it does work on device. I checked it on Galaxy Nexus. Will it not work on Emulator ?

Comment: I have no specific experience with encryption on the emulator. But I would not be surprised at all if it was just simply not implemented all the way on the emulator. There are plenty of other quirks that are a bit "off" about the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the encryption feature doesn't run on the emulator. If you want to test this feature without using a physical phone/tablet, you can work with Buildroid (Android port to VirtualBox) which now supports this feature : [Buildroid Blog](http://www.buildroid.org/blog/?p=159)

Dan.

Comment: The link is not working and my advice: Don't lookup Buildroid at Google on work. You get really NSFW ads when you open the blog in the first result.